# Is it possible to have multiple virtual machines with the same (guest) ip on the same host?

Tags: networking, iptables, virtualbox

What I try to achieve:

Multiple virtual machines (virtualbox) on a Debian host which communicate with another server (not with each other or the host). All VMs need to have the same static network settings (so that i can clone and use them without changing the settings in the guest). Every networking attempt of the VMs has to be redirected to the aforementioned server.

My current setup:

1. I create a tap on the host for each VM and use bridged networking to connect the VMs with the corresponding tap
2. All taps are connected with a bridge. The bridge has an ip address which is the gateway for the virtual machines.
3. The host as a dedicated interface which connects it to the server. This interface is also connected with the bridge
4. An iptables SNAT rule on this interface to connect the VMs with the server
5. An iptables DNAT rule redirects all traffic from the bridge to the server

This works so far. But with this setup the VMs cannot have the same ip address because they are connected via the bridge. I tried to SNAT the ip addresses on the taps but that didn't work.

Comment: *so that i can clone and use them without changing the settings in the guest* → Have you considered DHCP? Sounds much saner. Remember you can use DHCP reservations to give each VM a static IP via DHCP with all the config being on the DHCP server(s).

Comment: @derobert: yes, I'm currently using DHCP as workaround. But I hope there is a solution with static settings. I start and clone the VMs from a saved state and that leads to problems if they still have a DHCP lease.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* set up NAT with each guest on its on private network. First, you'd need to stop bridging all of their network interfaces together (after all, if they're all on the same switch, they're hardly on their own private networks).

Then you'd set up NAT rules, and *maybe* it'd work. But probably not—the outgoing path should work, but the return path is a problem. The NAT machinery gets a reply packet, NATs it back to the source 192.168.0.2 (or whatever). Then it passes it to routing... which sends it where? All the guests have that same IP address, all their interfaces have the same address/subnet mask.

So we need to fix routing. Thankfully, that's doable, with policy routing.

If you add in `-t mangle` rules for each guest (based on the source port, e.g., the vnet0 or whatever) you could mark the connections. Then you can route the response back (using `ip rule`) based on that mark.

That's a lot of config, but once you get it working, it's scriptable. It'll probably work. I haven't tested it. Whether its sane or not, well… I'd try to get DHCP working right personally. Consider what the next person to have to administer that will think (which may well be you in a few months once you've forgotten exactly how it works.)

Comment: _First, you'd need to stop bridging all of their network interfaces together_ - but how can I connect them with the NIC of the host?

Comment: @johnbaum via routing / forwarding, like you'd do on a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no. What you're trying to do is, from a networking perspective, identical to trying to have multiple physical hosts with the same IP. It won't work.

Comment: _multiple physical hosts with the same IP_ - But that is possible if they are not physically connected. Isn't it possible to simulate the same in my setup? The VMs do **not** have to communicate with each other.

Comment: They have to communicate with an external host, so they will be able to communicate with each other. It won't work.

Comment: The host is in a different network. It is possible that you and me have the same (private) ip right now. Although we communicate with the same stackexchange server.

Comment: It. Will. Not. Work. You and I may have the same private IP, but we're not on the same virtual host (local network).

Comment: thanks for your answer John. Is it possible to create several different virtual hosts (so that the guest(s) have the same IP) and to then route traffic to each of the different networks - somehow?